# Does Java socket get functionality from c socket

Tags: java, android, c, linux, sockets

I want to modify how Java.Net.Socket works for my own needs (within Android). I'm a bit confused on whether or not it makes use of the C socket within the Linux kernel. Is this the case? If so could I get some direction on where Java calls for functionality from C Socket.

Comment: Every language providing sockets eventually makes use of the `socket()` syscall in the kernel. So the answer is yes, even though the actual call is probably buried somewhere in the java virtual machine

Comment: So if I wanted to add functionality missing in the Java socket, best place to start is Dalvik or ART?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Android's architecture, but yeah, I'd say that would be a good start. Maybe someone that is more familiar with android specifics can help you here.

Comment: What actually you want modify? If this is for your app you can use C/C++ and call it from Java or even use some existing libraries. If you want modify something kernel or dalvik related you have to recompile Android for your device.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to provide information on why I want to do this. Custom AOSP is not a problem.